# How can multiple users authenticate R/RW/ADM? in azure container registry

Tags: azure, access-control, azure-container-registry

I've created an [Azure Container Registry](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-registry/), and I want to provide access control for some users.

How can multiple users authenticate R/RW/ADM?"

Comment: I assume by R/RW/ADM you mean user roles for read, read and write and admin access, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Service Principal" for that. Here are some links to help you understand that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal